# Android: ImageView with text and own shape

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gridlayout

I would like to create buttons with round corners, an image and a text but I have issues in centering text and icon.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        **android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"**>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnResult"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/result"
            android:background="@layout/round_corners"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/result"
            android:id="@+id/tvAnalysis"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            **android:layout_marginTop="180dp"**/>

</...
```

I need to specify the android:layout_marginLeft of the GridLayout to have it centered on my Nexus 5. On all other devices this is not feasable.

Any idea what I need to change to center the imageview/text combination?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12379075/745750

Answer (score 0):

For creating round corners for button ,

please create a xml lets called myshape.sml in drawable folder and paste below code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/header"/>

</shape>
```

If you want to add image to button and text then

```
  <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha"                               
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:textSize="14sp />
```

Please note here  `android:drawableLeft` is property in which you place icons to buttons

Answer (score 0):

Can You Try TextView with DrawableLeft(or as per your need, Right,top,bottom) Instade of Button & Imageview ?